# Fast way to in-place update one vector with another

Tags: c, optimization, trigonometry, angle

I have a vector A, represented by an angle and a length. I want to add vector B, updating the original A. B comes from a lookup table, so it can be represented in which ever way makes the computation easier.

Specifically, A is defined thusly:

```
uint16_t A_angle; // 0-65535 = 0-2π
int16_t A_length;
```

Approximations are fine. Checking for overflow is not necessary. A fast sin/cos approximation is available.

The fastest way I can think is to have B represented as a component vector, convert A to component, add A and B, convert the result back to angle/length and replace A. (This requires the addition of a fast asin/acos)

**I am not especially good at math and wonder if I am missing a more sensible approach?**

I am primarily looking for a general approach, but specific answers/comments about useful micro-optimizations in C is also interesting.

Comment: If you are doing lots of calculation in Cartesian coordinates, have you considered just storing all your vectors in Cartesian, and only convert to and from polar at the beginning and end.

Comment: It's a good point, and I evaluate this continuously. For example rotating vectors by a constant happens a lot, requiring polar. Your comment did make me think though; I might be able to squeeze in this at the same time as another operation requires the Cartesian value of A. (At some cost to code readability.) That makes converting back the only step.

Comment: Although rotation is an addition in polar, it's only 4 multiplies in cartesian, which is a lot cheaper than cos/sin/acos/asin.  I guess it depends on your exact breakdown of operations, though.

Comment: After some thinking, I think will be better off switching to Cartesian. If you sum up your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it. How do you rotate by an angle in Cartesian with 4 mults btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do a lot of additive operations, it would probably be worth considering storing everything in Cartesian coordinates, rather than polar.

Polar is well-suited to rotation operations (and scaling, I guess), but sticking with Cartesian (where a rotation is four multiplies, see below) is probably going to be cheaper than using cos/sin/acos/asin every time you want to do a vector addition.  Although, of course, it depends on the distribution of operations in your case.

FYI, a rotation in Cartesian coordinates is as follows (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

```
x' = x.cos(a) - y.sin(a)
y' = x.sin(a) + y.cos(a)
```

If `a` is known ahead of time, then `cos(a)` and `sin(a)` can be precomputed.

Comment: I knew "only 4 multiplies" was too good to be true. But yeah, I can probably approximate or precompute those values. Thanks.

Comment: @porgarmingduod your angles are `uint16_t`, 64K values isn't much, precomputing lookup tables will gain much if you're using trig functions a lot - if you don't, the few `sin` etc won't matter anyway.

Comment: CPU cache does not approve the size of your lookup table :)